# What is validation in foreign address column of netstat?

Tags: powershell, netstat

I am trying to learn about netstat command.

Foreign Address - The IP address and port number of the remote computer to which the socket is connected.

This is what I understood about Foreign Address.
But when I ran the command what I got in Foreign Address column is that **validation:port_number**

[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZJwC.png)

I didn't understood what is **validation** ?
Can someone please explain me? Or if I am wrong somewhere please show me the way.

Comment: validation is a DNS resolution of the IP your system is connecting to. If you run `nslookup validation`, you should have a response. `netstat -n` should reveal the IP. Then you can compare the ports in the `foreign address` column. By default, `netstat` will try to do reverse name lookup of the IP on that connected port.

Comment: @AdminOfThings So, is **validation** a Domain name ?? And your last line means that by default netstat command provides Domain Name?

Comment: It is a hostname that either has a DNS record or is in your local hosts file.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks for answering.